# What are the options for group-membership-based access control in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, cancan, access-control

For Rails I see quite a few gem options for role-based access control (cancan, cantango, etc.)  However, I'm not finding any gems for group-membership-based access control.  Here is a simplified description of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
Users: a, b, c, d 
Groups: y, z
Group Membership: y has a and b; z has c and d
Posts: m, n
Ownership: a owns m; c owns n

Group y is marked as a public group. m can be seen by all users
Group z is marked as a private group.  n can only be seen by c and d
```

So nothing too fancy or complex, essentially a capability similar to file system access control (e.g. read-write-execute across owner-group-public [without the 'execute' of course].)

It looks like Radiant (with some extra plug-ins) can provide page-level group-membership access control, but I don't want/need a whole CMS and I would prefer something that is model-based (like cancan) vs. page/path based. (BTW, I'm using Devise for my user model - is there something in Devise I missed?)

How are private/public user groupings implemented in Rails?  Only through a Rails-based CMS?  Am I missing something basic?  Or is this use-case rarely tackled in the Rails community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for this and thought I would post it in case anyone else is looking for it.

CanCan does support group capability via "Hash of Conditions".  The idea is that `post` is tagged with a `:group_id` (`belongs_to` a `group`) and `users` `has_many` `groups`.  Then you can set up the "hash of conditions" within the `can` statement as follows:

```
can :manage, Post, :group => { :id => user.group_ids }
```

The "hash of conditions" is documented further here:

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities

Thanks to @Jason_Noble for pointing me back to the cancan docs where I finally found it.

p.s. one implementation note.  If you wish to have some Posts public and some Posts private, you can set up a default group of which each user is a member.  All public Posts should then be tagged with the default group_id.

Answer (score 0):

I would use CanCan and do something like:

```
can :view_post, User if user.is_member_of_group?(z)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Jason.  The challenge I see with this approach is that all posts across the entire site would now be blocked from view unless the user is a member.  If the post is created by someone not in a protected group, then the "user.is_member_of_group?" logic needs to be avoided.  To avoid it, I guess that I could have a :group_id field in each post record.  If post.has_group? then I could use the membership test that you suggested above.  I don't have a lot of experience with CanCan, can you somehow get the post instance into the:  "can :action, :model do .... end" test?

Comment: I would test drive what you want.  Start with https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/master/spec/cancan/model_adapters/active_record_adapter_spec.rb.  I would guess you could have can :view_post, Post unless Post.protected? would let anyone view it, then you have Post.protected? see if the original poster is in a protected group and return true/false.

Comment: Again, I highly suggest you test drive out what you want.  Look at line 88 of https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/master/spec/cancan/model_adapters/active_record_adapter_spec.rb where he creates 4 articles, then verifies that you can see certain articles...